# PHP TIME converting?

Tags: php, time

I have something in my database that shows the time when the users who signed up on my recorded .. When the person makes the user saves the script (time ();) currently in the database under the variable name "REGTIM".

If I use echo to print it out, I get for example:

1375202508

How can I make this a date if it is possible? or for example as mentioned below.

for example: `08/06/2013 2:11`

Answer (score 2):

You could have got the answer to that with a little bit of searching. But here you go:

```
echo date('m/d/Y h:m', 1375202508); // 07/30/2013 10:07 -- 12-hour format
echo date('m/d/Y H:m', 1375202508); // 07/30/2013 22:07 -- 24-hour format
```

See the documentation for more options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use date() function with timestamp mention in the second argument,

```
date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

or in your case:

```
date('m/d/Y H:m', 1375202508);
```

you can read more on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

that's probably just a unix timestamp, so use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `DATE_FORMAT()` to do the conversion/formatting inside your query, or use [`date()`](http://php.net/date) in PHP to work with the timestamp directly.

e.g.

```
echo date('d/m/Y h:m', $timestamp)
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%d/%m/%y %h:%m', FROM_UNIXTIME(REGTIM))
```